# .NET ImageList becomes corrupt occasionally

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

With a Winforms .net application, we have an issue where an image list occasionally becomes corrupted.

By corrupted I mean that the count of the number of images will be wrong and/or the images may have been replaced by system images (like dialog box icons).

For example, the screenshot below shows the `imageInfoCollection` showing the correct number, but the count showing the incorrect number.

[image]

The image list is on a form that is opened repeatedly by the user throughout the use of the application. The image list is used by a tab control on the form.

The issue occurs only occasionally, anywhere between every 5 and 20 times of opening the form.

The code to load the imagelist is built by the designer, and uses images from the resources:

```
this.imageListCallTakingScreen.ImageStream = ((System.Windows.Forms.ImageListStreamer)(resources.GetObject("imageListCallTakingScreen.ImageStream")));
this.imageListCallTakingScreen.TransparentColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
this.imageListCallTakingScreen.Images.SetKeyName(0, "spinner.png");
this.imageListCallTakingScreen.Images.SetKeyName(1, "recommendation-star.png");
this.imageListCallTakingScreen.Images.SetKeyName(2, "recommendation-star_red.png");
this.imageListCallTakingScreen.Images.SetKeyName(3, "recommendation-star - Transparent.png");
this.imageListCallTakingScreen.Images.SetKeyName(4, "Initialisation_fail16.png");
this.imageListCallTakingScreen.Images.SetKeyName(5, "information_white.png");
this.imageListCallTakingScreen.Images.SetKeyName(6, "Check-icon.png");
```

The imagelist isn't used anywhere other than in the designer.cs code to create it and wire it up to the tab control (except for the error trapping line I have put in):

[image]

Ideas? We are stuck on this one and google doesn't turn much up.

Comment: Any multi-threading going on in your application?

Comment: yes, a lot of other threads. This particular block of code is called from within an Invoke() though.

Comment: `The issue occurs only occasionally` - That is usually a common symptom of a concurrency issue.  Take a look at your code that writes to the imageList and make sure it is properly synchronized.

Comment: We had the same thoughts on threading, and it possibly is the root of it. However, the image list is only ever written to on the load of the form in the designer.cs file. This is always invoked on the UI thread.

Comment: Is it assigned using a linq-to-object query (or an `IEnumerable`)?  Could it be read by a worker thread before the UI thread has finished writing everything to it?

Comment: I've updated the Q to show all references to it. It isn't used in Linq. The only way we access it programatically is to set the imageindex of tabs in the tab control. It is possible that this may be done in a worker thread, but I doubt it. I'll double check.

Comment: double checked, image index only ever set from an Invoke(). Thanks for your help by the way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The imageInfoCollection field properly tracks the number of images you have in the ImageList.  The Count property tracks the number of images that are actually present in the native Windows imagelist control.

There's only one way those values could have a mismatch that I can think of.  Your program is leaking GDI object handles.  A fairly common problem in Winform apps.  That works for quite a while until you reach the operating system quota for such handles, after you've consumed 10,000 of them then Windows stops allowing you to create more.  The error checking in the .NET wrapper class is not entirely kosher so this can happen without an exception getting generated.  You'll see some more strange painting artifacts when you hit that limit btw.

You can get a basic diagnostic from Task Manager, Processes tab.  Use View + Select columns and tick GDI Objects and USER objects.  Observe these values while you operate the program like a user would.  A steadily climbing value for GDI Objects spells doom.  A hint that you are forgetting to use the *using* statement to dispose System.Drawing objects.  And the garbage collector not running often enough to keep you out of trouble.  You need to fix this in your code so the counter remains stable at, say, no more than several hundred objects.

A steadily climbing value for USER Objects is also a *very* common Winforms bug.  That's a pretty fatal one, it will jack-up the GDI object count as well and the GC cannot fix this problem.  This will happen when you remove controls in your code with Controls.Remove/At() or Controls.Clear() and forget to dispose the removed control objects.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. We have had issues with GDI handles leaking in the past and managed to program around these. The imagelist is added by the designer, does that need any other special handling (like disposing of) other than what is built by the designed. I guess you are also suggesting that this may be a symptom of leaks elsewhere in the application, rather than a cause?

Comment: Well, that certainly fits the pattern.  Yes, "elsewhere" is the issue, the designer code isn't the problem.  Don't program "around them", fix the bugs.  If you need help to find them beyond the TaskMgr.exe diagnostic and a thorough code review then use a good .NET memory profiler.  If you're desperate for a quick fix and verified that it isn't a USER Objects problem then forcing the GC to run periodically is a quick & dirty workaround.

Comment: Marked as answer because yes this is probably the route of the issue. We have tracked it down to a third party control gobbling USER Object and GDI Handles.